# Strange result when specifying both font-family and font-size on the same element in Firefox 78

Tags: html, css, firefox

Repro example ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnaov39L/3/)):

```
<div style="font-family: serif; font-size: x-large;">Hello World</div>

<div style="font-family: serif">
  <div style="font-size: x-large;">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

yields the following (unexpected) result in Firefox 78.0.1 (64-bit, Windows 10):

[image: Screenshot]

On Google Chrome the two lines have the same font size (as expected).

Is this some strange corner case of the CSS spec or did I stumble upon a Firefox rendering bug?

Comment: it's seems to be a bug, it's fine on my firefox (same configuration as yours)

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Thanks, that's good to know. I was able to reproduce it on 2 machines in my office, I'll try a few more then.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Are you sure you have exactly the same Firefox version on exactly the same OS? I just tried it on my home machine and I can reproduce it there as well...

Comment: yes the same but I didn't update to the recent version so it's probably your issue. I generally don't do updates early because there is always bugs so I wait few minor releases later

Comment: That's a v78 rendering bug.There's nothing in the specs that would justify that.